# Why can't I get past the Daytower after clearing all corrupted zones in the valley?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

As soon as I was able to leave the Sacred Grounds, I stopped doing the main quest and began exploring.

When I attempted to go to the second Tallneck, however, I ran into the Daytower and I was told that the gates would remain sealed until all corrupted zones in the valley had been cleared. After that, I went and cleared every corrupted zone I could find and explored every part of the map that I could, until there didn't seem to be any more corrupted zones.

However, the Carja guards still refuse to let me pass, despite having cleared all corrupted zones on the accessible area of the map. How do I get through the gates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually aren't able to pass through this gate until you've completed the Main Quest "A Seeker At The Gates". Despite telling you that you need to clear all corrupted zones in the valley, you only actually need to clear two of them in order to progress the quest. After this, you'll have to

> defend the Daytower from more corrupted Machines.

After which point, you'll be allowed to pass through the gates into Carja.

Comment: Yes, the dialogue is weird there if you've never visited Daytower before that point.  Aloy says, "*Now* will you let me in?" as though she'd previously been denied entry.